# How to fix "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed" when encrypting and decrypting in the same process

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, rijndael

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt an xml file. The program trys to open, edit, and reencrypt the data, But I get the error "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed." When I encrypt, then decrypt running the program twice, It works just fine, but the program creates an error when doing them both.

This is a very common error, but also a very vague one, with many different "scenarios". I've searched for a while one ways to fix it, and I've tried all of the "fixes" online. None have worked yet.

```cs
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
        public static void encFile(string input, string password)
        {
            GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(password, GCHandleType.Pinned);

            FileEncrypt(input, password);

            ZeroMemory(gch.AddrOfPinnedObject(), password.Length * 2);
            gch.Free();
        }
        public static string output;
        public static void decFile(string input, string password)
        {
            GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(password, GCHandleType.Pinned);

            // Decrypt the file
            output = FileDecrypt(input, password);

        }

        [DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint = "RtlZeroMemory")]
        public static extern bool ZeroMemory(IntPtr Destination, int Length);

        /// <summary>
        /// Encrypts a file from its path and a plain password.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="inputFile"></param>
        /// <param name="password"></param>
        private static void FileEncrypt(string inputFile, string password)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(Path.GetDirectoryName(inputFile) + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(inputFile) + ".dat", Crypto.EncryptStringAES(File.ReadAllText(inputFile), "Password123!"));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Decrypts an encrypted file with the FileEncrypt method through its path and the plain password.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="inputFile"></param>
        /// <param name="outputFile"></param>
        /// <param name="password"></param>
        private static string FileDecrypt(string inputFile, string password)
        {
            return Crypto.DecryptStringAES(File.ReadAllText(inputFile), password);
        }
    }
    public class Crypto
    {

        //While an app specific salt is not the best practice for
        //password based encryption, it's probably safe enough as long as
        //it is truly uncommon. Also too much work to alter this answer otherwise.
        private static byte[] _salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("rxONBa*&e03!%76N9mBlbR#@Xl&A&w");

        /// <summary>
        /// Encrypt the given string using AES.  The string can be decrypted using 
        /// DecryptStringAES().  The sharedSecret parameters must match.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="plainText">The text to encrypt.</param>
        /// <param name="sharedSecret">A password used to generate a key for encryption.</param>
        public static string EncryptStringAES(string plainText, string sharedSecret)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(plainText))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sharedSecret))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("sharedSecret");

            string outStr = null;                       // Encrypted string to return
            RijndaelManaged aesAlg = null;              // RijndaelManaged object used to encrypt the data.

            try
            {
                // generate the key from the shared secret and the salt
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(sharedSecret, _salt);

                // Create a RijndaelManaged object
                aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
                aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);
                aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for encryption.
                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    // prepend the IV
                    msEncrypt.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(aesAlg.IV.Length), 0, sizeof(int));
                    msEncrypt.Write(aesAlg.IV, 0, aesAlg.IV.Length);
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {
                            //Write all data to the stream.
                            swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                        }
                    }
                    outStr = Convert.ToBase64String(msEncrypt.ToArray());
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // Clear the RijndaelManaged object.
                if (aesAlg != null)
                    aesAlg.Clear();
            }

            // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
            return outStr;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Decrypt the given string.  Assumes the string was encrypted using 
        /// EncryptStringAES(), using an identical sharedSecret.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cipherText">The text to decrypt.</param>
        /// <param name="sharedSecret">A password used to generate a key for decryption.</param>
        public static string DecryptStringAES(string cipherText, string sharedSecret)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cipherText))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sharedSecret))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("sharedSecret");

            // Declare the RijndaelManaged object
            // used to decrypt the data.
            RijndaelManaged aesAlg = null;

            // Declare the string used to hold
            // the decrypted text.
            string plaintext = null;

            try
            {
                // generate the key from the shared secret and the salt
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(sharedSecret, _salt);

                // Create the streams used for decryption.                
                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                {
                    // Create a RijndaelManaged object
                    // with the specified key and IV.
                    aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
                    aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);
                    // Get the initialization vector from the encrypted stream
                    aesAlg.IV = ReadByteArray(msDecrypt);
                    aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                    // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                    ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))

                            // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                            // and place them in a string.
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // Clear the RijndaelManaged object.
                if (aesAlg != null)
                    aesAlg.Clear();
            }

            return plaintext;
        }

        private static byte[] ReadByteArray(Stream s)
        {
            byte[] rawLength = new byte[sizeof(int)];
            if (s.Read(rawLength, 0, rawLength.Length) != rawLength.Length)
            {
                throw new SystemException("Stream did not contain properly formatted byte array");
            }

            byte[] buffer = new byte[BitConverter.ToInt32(rawLength, 0)];
            if (s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) != buffer.Length)
            {
                throw new SystemException("Did not read byte array properly");
            }

            return buffer;
        }
    }
```

Running the following code that encrypts then decrypts will produce the error:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string password = "Password123!";
            encFile(@"C:\DIR\test.xml", password);
            decFile(@"C:\DIR\test.dat", password);
            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
```

But if you try first running this code that only encrypts the file:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string password = "Password123!";
            encFile(@"C:\DIR\test.xml", password);
        }
```

and then decrypting the file in another process after the encryption:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string password = "Password123!";
            decFile(@"C:\DIR\test.dat", password);
            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
```

Then the program will output the contents correctly, without an error.

How can I encrypt and decrypt the file in one run, without any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `password`, and the parameter with the same name, point to the same constant string. The first of your methods will zero that string out.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string password = "Password123!";

        encFile(@"C:\KaliPatriot\test.xml", password);
        // password is now "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"            
        decFile(@"C:\KaliPatriot\test.dat", password);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
```

Using  a string like this is very dangerous. Strings are supposed (and assumed) to be immutable and .NET also uses interning for strings.

You have managed to get UB (Undefined Behaviour) in C#, not something to be proud of.